# MongoDB maximum document size

Tags: mongodb, nosql, bson

As per the following link, the limit for a document size is 16MB. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

However, I'm a little confused as to what a document is. For example,

```
{
 {
   "name": "test",
   "_id": "4"
 },
 {
   "name": "test2",
   "_id": "5"
}
```

Does the above file refer to 1 document or 2 documents? And should the size of the entire file be less than 16MB, or the size of 1 element/document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mongodb, collection stores documents.

Every document is a [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) stored internally as a [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Find the mongodb documentation here on [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/).

In the sample data, there are two documents:

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "_id": "4"
 }
```

and

```
{
   "name": "test2",
   "_id": "5"
}
```

Every such a document has a limit of 16MB while storing in mongodb.
  For storing documents size greater than 16MB consider using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 documents in the collection. In mongo, one document should contain maximum of 16MB,not more than that.